# Showing and hiding a corresponding list when clicking on an image with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, image, display

I am trying to show and hide a specific list of text when a certain image is clicked. For example: When I click the 5K/10K events image, the list under the div id of 5K displays and only that list, and when I click the image again it hides that list. So far I am able to make the list show and hide, but it shows all of them instead of the specific list. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Hides the lists on load
    $('h3').hide();
    $('ul').hide();
    
    // Click on a picture to show the corresponding list
    $("img[src='images/run1.jpg']").click(function(){
      $('ul').toggle();
    });
    
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->
  
  <div id="main">
  </div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->
  
  <div id="pics">
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="5k">
        <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Mini Sprint</br>10/30/20</br>Memorial Park</br>Appleton</li>
          <li>Iron Horse</br>11/06/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Twilight Trail</br>11/13/20</br>River's Edge Park</br>Wrightstown</li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="half">
        <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/20</br>Pierce Park</br>Appleton</li>
          <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/20</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
    </div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="full">
        <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/20</br>Pamperin Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/20</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/20</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->
    
  </div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect, `$('ul')` will select all lists.

You may change your `click` handler to look like this in order to get the image's list:

```
    $("img").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.races').find('ul').toggle();
    });
```

This will toggle the list of an image when the image is clicked:

Explanation:

```
$("img")
```

will select all images (`img` tag)

```
$(this)
```

inside the `click` handler, the `this` keyword will reference the clicked image

```
.siblings('.races').find('ul')
```

This will find the `races` class which is in the same level of depth as the image element (`nextAll` with a selector will also suffice)

And the select element which is currently the list after the image is then toggled.

here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hides the lists on load
    $('h3').hide();
    $('ul').hide();
    
    // Click on a picture to show the corresponding list
    $("img").click(function(){
      $('ul').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.races').find('ul').toggle();
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->
  
  <div id="main">
  </div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->
  
  <div id="pics">
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="5k">
        <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Mini Sprint<br>10/30/20<br>Memorial Park<br>Appleton</li>
          <li>Iron Horse<br>11/06/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Twilight Trail<br>11/13/20<br>River's Edge Park<br>Wrightstown</li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="half">
        <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/20<br>Pierce Park<br>Appleton</li>
          <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/20<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
    </div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->
    
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
      <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>
      
      <div class="races" id="full">
        <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/20<br>Pamperin Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/20<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/20<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
    </div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->
    
  </div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! But now I am trying to make it so if a list is visible and I make a new one visible, the one that was first visible goes away and the new one becomes visible.

Comment: @Tony Changed The snippet to fit your need

Answer (score 0):

Just I try like below. It's working but if you want to specific ul hide/show, you must be give a name/id/class.

```
$("img[src='images/run1.jpg']").click(function(){
   $('ul').toggle();
   $(this).hide();
   var img = $(this).prop('name');
   var div = $(this).parent();
   $(div).prepend('<a class="showImage" data-img-name="'+img+'" href="#">Show Image</a>');
});
        
$(document.body).on('click', '.showImage', function() {
   var img = $(this).data('img-name');
   var selector = 'img[name='+img+']';
   $(selector).show();
   $('ul').hide();
   $(this).remove();
})

<img src="images/run1.jpg" name='img1' />
```